# Unable to pass variable

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to pass number of post show from widget.I stored it as $entry

my code

```
<?php query_posts( array('post_type' => array('post'),'order' => 'DESC','posts_per_page' => '.$entry.') ); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: try
<?php query_posts( array('post_type' => array('post'),'order' => 'DESC','posts_per_page' => $entry) ); ?>

Comment: First of all, dont use `query_posts`, Check the [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) for better explanation. and can you upload the related codes ie: of the widget for a clearer picture. and here you have a syntax error as pointed by @Bainternet

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Bainternet

```
<?php query_posts( array('post_type' => array('post'),'order' => 'DESC','posts_per_page' => $entry) ); ?>
```